# Рекурсивный поиск файлов и папок

Tags: c++, winapi

Нужно реализовать поиск файлов/папок в подкаталогах. `Path` это путь к исходной папке, аргумент `b` это маска для поиска. Проблема в том что алгоритм проходит все папки и подкаталоги на диске, но находит только файлы из исходного паки `Path`.

```
void FindFileRecursive(string  & Path, char *b, HWND fList)
{
    bool flag = false;
    static int i = 0;


    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
    string  Mask = Path + "*";
    HANDLE fFind = FindFirstFile(Mask.c_str(), &FindData);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != fFind)
    {
        do
        {
            if (Find::IsNotDotName(&FindData.cFileName[0]))
            {
                string FullPath = Path + &FindData.cFileName[0] + "\\";
                if (Find::IsDirectory(FindData.dwFileAttributes))
                    FindFileRecursive(FullPath, b, fList);
                else
                {
                    _finddata_t fd;
                    int OK = _findfirst(FullPath.c_str(), &fd);
                    int result = OK;
                    INT i = 0;
                    while (result != -1)
                    {
                        char *q = NULL;
                        if (b[0] == '*')
                        {
                            ++b;
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        if (flag)
                            q = strstr(fd.name, b);
                        if (strncmp(b, fd.name, strlen(fd.name)) == 0 || q != NULL)
                        {
                            LVITEM LvItem;
                            memset(&LvItem, 0, sizeof(LvItem));
                            LvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
                            LvItem.cchTextMax = 256;
                            LvItem.iItem = i;        
                            LvItem.iSubItem = 0;    
                            LvItem.pszText = fd.name;

                            SendMessage(fList, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&LvItem); 
                            char Temp[100];
                            LvItem.iSubItem = 2;
                            sprintf_s(Temp, "%s", fd.name);
                            LvItem.pszText = Temp;
                            SendMessage(fList, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&LvItem); 


                            LvItem.iSubItem = 3;
                            sprintf_s(Temp, "%f", fd.size);
                            LvItem.pszText = "0";
                            if (fd.size != NULL)
                                LvItem.pszText = Temp;
                            SendMessage(fList, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&LvItem);

                            LvItem.iSubItem = 1;
                            ctime_s(Temp, 30, &fd.time_write);
                            LvItem.pszText = Temp;
                            SendMessage(fList, LVM_SETITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&LvItem);
                            i++;
                        }
                        result = _findnext(OK, &fd);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (NULL != FindNextFile(fFind, &FindData));
    }
    FindClose(fFind);

}
```

Comment: А вы не забываете добавить бекслеш в конец пути? Поставьте брейкпойнт и посмотрите, что приходит в функцию.

Comment: @VladD, добавил бекслеш, и теперь в отладчике видно что рекурсия работает и программа бегает по папкам.
Как я понимаю проблема в  int OK = _findfirst(FullPath.c_str(), &fd), ОК всегда -1, хотя путь в findfirst передается вроде правильно :  "C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-21-1037564483-3546990408-930324707-1001\\$I41I3N0\\*"

Comment: Ну, на `$Recycle.Bin` у программы может быть просто нету прав доступа (проверьте в Проводнике). Не забывайте после получения -1 проверить `errno`, там лежит реально случившаяся ошибка. А с остальными каталогами проблем нет?

Comment: @VladD, проблема со всеми каталогами

Comment: А что в `errno`?

Comment: @vlad errno возвращает 22

Comment: Отлично, вы уже посмотрели, что это означает?

Comment: @VladD, неправильный аргумент. Но я не могу понять почему это он неправильный, и как исправить.

Comment: Отлично. А давайте-ка посмотрим, что за аргументы вы передаёте. Чему равны **в точности** аргументы вызова, когда возникает _самая первая_ ошибка?

Comment: Например, `"C:\\$Recycle.Bin\\S-1-5-21-1037564483-3546990408-930324707-1001\\$I41I3N0\*"` выглядит подозрительно: один раз двойной слеш, один раз одинарный?

Comment: Вы забили `_findclose(&fd)`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите небольшой пример фактической структры каталогов, того что находит алгоритм и того что вы хотите получить

Comment: Правильно я понимаю: агрумент `Path` это путь к исходной папке, аргумент `b` это маска для поиска?

Comment: @Lightness Вопрос правте, сюда не надо писать.

Comment: Поясните фразу "только файлы из НЕ подкаталогов" это значит только файлы из исходной папки?

Comment: @VladD, попробовал и с двумя и с одним флешом в конце, результат не меняется

Comment: @Cerbo, именно так

Comment: Подождите, не, вот это «я попробовал и так и так» — это какой-то ужас. Вы программист или блондинк? Вы должны сделать как правильно, и должно работать. У вас двойной слеш реально в строке, или в строковом литерале? Чему равна длина `"C:\\"` в вашей программе? И как может это быть с одним слешем?

Comment: @VladD, извините, я неправильно выразился. У меня двойной слеш реально в строке.Просто реально уже паника, 2 дня биться над вроде бы несложным заданием

Comment: @Lightness Функция `Find::IsNotDotName` проверяет `..` и `.`?

Comment: Да, она проверяет . и ..

Comment: Какой тип у TCHAR? Вернее какие настройки строк в проекте (вкладка General)

Comment: Включен multi-byte

Comment: Поставьте однобайтовые строки и проверяйте

Comment: В ветке в которой вы имена файлов проверяете и добавляете в список, закоментируйте условия фильтрации, то есть выводите все файлы которые найдутся без условий

Comment: Добавляются в лист все файлы, и дублируются несколько раз

Comment: @Lightness: Вот! Это может и быть причиной. Нужен одинарный слеш. Двойной слеш по идее только в строковых константах, и он превращается в реально одинарный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С начала я вам рекомендую использовать вот такое объявление для использования функций WinApi:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> StdString;
```

Ошибка у вас в фильтрации файлов, что-то там темное присходит. Зачем вы ее вручную делаете когда `FindFirstFile` умеет это все прекрасно. Вот как должна выглядеть функция:

```
void ScanFolder(const StdString & folder, const StdString & mask, DWORD attrs, HWND fList)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA find_data   = {0};   
    HANDLE          find_handle = FindFirstFile(  (folder + mask).c_str()
                                                , &find_data         );

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == find_handle)
    {
        // ругаемся
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if(   (attrs & find_data.dwFileAttributes) 
                && !Find::IsNotDotName(find_data.cFileName) )
            {
                // обрабатываем найденое
            }
        }
        while(FindNextFile(find_handle, &find_data))

        FindClose(find_handle);
    }
}

void FindFileRecursive(StdString start_path, const StdString & mask, DWORD attrs, HWND fList)
{

    start_path = rtrim(start_path) + _T(\\);

    ScanFolder(start_path, mask, attrs, fList);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA folder_data = {0};
    HANDLE          folder_find = FindFirstFileEx
    (
          (start_path + _T("*")).c_str()
        ,  FindExInfoStandard
        , &folder_data         
        ,  FindExSearchLimitToDirectories // ищем папки
        ,  NULL
        ,  FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH
    );

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == folder_find)
    {
        // ругаемся
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if(   (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & folder_data.dwFileAttributes) 
                && !Find::IsNotDotName(folder_data.cFileName)       )
            {
                FindFileRecursive(  start_path + folder_data.cFileName
                                  , mask
                                  , attrs
                                  , fList  );
            }
        }
        while(FindNextFile(folder_find, &folder_data))

        FindClose(folder_find);
    }
}
```

Функция обрезки строки (взята [от сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring)):

```
 static inline StdString & rtrim(StdString & s)
 {
    s.erase
    (
       std::find_if(  s.rbegin()
                    , s.rend()
                    , std::not1(std::ptr_fun<int, int>(std::isspace))).base()
     , s.end()
    );
    return s;
 }
```