# Реализация программы для поиска файла

Tags: c++

Необходимо найти некоторый файл fileName.*

Условия:

1. Каталог, в котором лежит файл - неизвестен
2. Если найдено более одного файла - указать, какой из них изменялся в последнюю очередь

Comment: Этот вопрос уже был смотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453871/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Answer (score 2):

`FindFirstFile` + `FindNextFile` + `FindClose` для поиска.

В процессе поиска в поле `ftLastWriteTime` структуры `WIN32_FIND_DATA` будет содержаться время последней записи. Правда, я не знаю что там для каталога будет.

Comment: А можно пример? с++ console

Comment: @lazigi посмотрите в MSDN, примеры есть.

Comment: что-то они не работают (((

Comment: @lazigi очень сомневаюсь что для столь употребимых функций в MSDN некорректные примеры...